# how can i show two different color's pin annotation in MKMapView?

Tags: ios4, mkmapview, mkannotation

i am using MKMapView Annotation for Displaying pin's.In my Project there are many number of pin's dropping.i want to just show the difference between current location's pin color and other pin's color.so how can i show two different pin's color for current location and other location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   // Identify which pin is being selected  
   if([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Current Location"]) 
   {   
     annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
   }
```

also check this link:
[Issue with Map Annotation and MKMapView in iOS 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383917/issue-with-map-annotation-and-mkmapview-in-ios-4-2)