# Ios 4 - Mkmap placing custom annotations problem

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am working on  MKMap View which shows current location based on location coordinate and other custom annotations . It showing correctly on the Iphone 3gs but on iphone 4.0 or above it does not show the custom annotations every time (randomly it showing only green pin not the other ) . what can be the problem ? is there a problem in ios 4.0 and above ? if so how can we solve it .can  anyone  help me

Thanks

Code from viewForAnnotation method...

```
if ([annotation isMemberOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) 
{ 
    return nil; 
} 

if (annotation==self.normalAnnotation) 
{ 
    NSLog(@"green pin"); 
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"NormalAnnotation"] autorelease]; 
    annotationView.canShowCallout = NO; 
    annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen; 
    return annotationView; 
} 
else 
{ 
    NSLog(@"Custom pin"); 
    Marker *obj = [database getMarkerWithName:[annotation title]]; 
    MKAnnotationView *newAnnotation=[[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation1"]autorelease]; 
    newAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:obj.markerImage]; 
    newAnnotation.canShowCallout=YES; 
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]; 
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    [button setTag:obj.markerID]; 
    newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView=button; 
    //annotation.annotationObj = newAnnotation; 
    return newAnnotation; 
}
```

Comment: Show the code for your viewForAnnotation method.

Comment: Hi Thanks for ur response , here is my code

Comment: if ([annotation isMemberOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
  {
   return nil;
  }
 
 if (annotation==self.normalAnnotation)
 {
  NSLog(@"green pin");
  MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                      reuseIdentifier:@"NormalAnnotation"] autorelease];
  annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
  annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
  return annotationView;
 }
 else 
 {
  NSLog(@"Custom pin");
  Marker *obj = [database getMarkerWithName:[annotation title]];

Comment: MKAnnotationView *newAnnotation=[[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation1"]autorelease];
  newAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:obj.markerImage];
  
  newAnnotation.canShowCallout=YES;
  
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [button setTag:obj.markerID];
  newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView=button;
  
  //annotation.annotationObj = newAnnotation;
  return newAnnotation;
  
  
 }

Comment: It's better to edit the question and add the code there instead of putting so much in the comments.

Comment: Not certain but might be that you are always creating a new view every time annotation needs to be displayed.  That is, you are not re-using views (to minimize memory requirements) by using `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier`.  See Apple's sample map apps like MapCallouts to see how viewForAnnotation should be implemented.  Separately: instead of implementing your own action method for the button (and tagging it), use calloutAccessoryControlTapped (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383917/issue-with-map-annotation-and-mkmapview-in-ios-4-2/4388770#4388770)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this , it happens because the pins are redrawing again and again since [location manager stopUpdatingLocation]is not working properly .so with bool variable I stop to call the class which initializes the Mapview again and again.

@aBitObvious : Thank u very much for ur support thanks...