# selector adding parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mapkit

What I want to do is basically send some form of id with my button so I can calculate which one has been clicked. My buttons get dynamically created and all of them execute the same function that loads a new view, I want to know which button was clicked so I can display the correct data on the new view.

I have an NSMutableArray of annotations that I add a button to the details of the pin. The button works and it loads the next view, but I want to figure out which button was pressed.

I use a singleton with an NSMutableArray called array. The singleton name is Helper

What I did was:

```
Helper* array = [Helper sharedManager];
int clickedNum = [array.array indexOfObject:annotation];
[myDetailButton setTag:clickedNum];
[myDetailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moreInfo:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

That is where i create the annotations that go unto the map. The next line is my function ID

```
- (IBAction)moreInfo:(UIButton*)sender
```

And this is where I want to retrieve the tag

```
Helper *array = [Helper sharedManager];
array.clicked = sender.tag;
```

When I run this and click on the button in one of my annotations I get an exception saying NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: -(MapViewController moreInfo:event:]

Any help would be appriciated

Edit:

As requested the interface for helper:

```
@interface Helper : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *array;
    int clicked;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (nonatomic) int clicked;

+(id)sharedManager;

@end
```

Also I thought it wise to add:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
static NSString *identifier = @"Events";
MKPinAnnotationView *retval = nil;
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Events class]]) 
{

    (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (retval == nil) {
        retval = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
        Helper *array = [Helper sharedManager];
        int clickedNum = [array.array indexOfObject:annotation];
        // Set up the Left callout
        UIButton *myDetailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        myDetailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
        myDetailButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        myDetailButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
        [myDetailButton setTag:clickedNum];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testing tag: %@", clickedNum]);
        [myDetailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moreInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        // Set the image for the button
        [myDetailButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon72.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // Set the button as the callout view
        retval.leftCalloutAccessoryView = myDetailButton;
    }


    if (retval) {
        [retval setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen];
        retval.animatesDrop = YES;
        retval.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
}

return retval;   
}
```

Comment: Are these buttons set as callout accessory views in the viewForAnnotation method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method `moreInfo:` doesn't match what you have set as the selector in

```
[myDetailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moreInfo:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

So change that to

```
[myDetailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moreInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Or change the method definition.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was going to write, so it *must* be correct.

Comment: @Deepak I changed the sellector. It now goes to the next view but the contents of array.clicked is now (null) when I put it in a UILable

Comment: @Armand Can you add the interface for `Helper`? How do you set it in the label? Does logging the value give you the correct value?

Comment: @Deepak I added the interface. In the label I just say label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", array.clicked]; Logging also gives me null.

Comment: @Armand `clicked` is an `int` so it should be `%d` and not `%@`. However it looks like `array` is `nil`. Can you confirm that too (Replace `array.clicked` with `array` in the log statement)? How are you getting the array in the other view controller.

Comment: @deepak you are now my hero, changing to %d showed me the tags, now I have another question and I know it is noob but my brain is now tired. Each time I click the button that adds the annotations it adds them all to an array, so I get duplicate values, now my question is simple, how to I remove them from the array in one fluent move or must I remove them 1 by 1 in a loop

Comment: It depends on how you are adding them but [`NSSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is something you can look into.

Comment: @Deepak Now I am using [array.array removeAllObjects]; and it is giving me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Although Deepak's answer is correct and will work, since your buttons are annotation callout accessory views, there is an easier way to tell which annotation's button was selected.

Instead of adding your own target+action, use the map view's `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` delegate method which will get called when a callout view is tapped.  There, the annotation is available as `view.annotation`.  You don't need to set the button tag or use the annotation's index.

For an example, see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383917/issue-with-map-annotation-and-mkmapview-in-ios-4-2/4388770#4388770).

A separate issue is that in your viewForAnnotation method, you are calling `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` but not doing anything with the result (so not getting any re-use).  Instead, it should be assigned to `retval` and inside the last `if`, set `retval.annotation`.

Comment: I have no idea how to use that delicate method. And I don't fully understand what you are saying about dequeueReusable.....

Comment: The viewForAnnotation method you've already written is also a delegate method which the map view calls when it needs an annotation view.  The calloutAccessoryControlTapped method is just another delegate method like viewForAnnotation that you can implement and the map view will call it when a callout button is tapped.  For the dequeue, maybe [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKMapView) will help.

Comment: Also, search for "dequeue" on the [Annotating Maps page of the Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html).